# How can I create a tree structure in adf using single database table?

Tags: java, collections, oracle-adf

```
This is the constructor code:

    public TreeExample() throws SQLException {
        TreeItem node1 = null;

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xyz";
        String user = "dummy";
        String password = "dummy";

        root = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM HEALTH_CHECK_QUERIES ORDER BY HEADER_TYPE ASC";

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        String previousheadernode = "First";
        while (result.next()) {

            String headernode = result.getString("Header_Type");
            String childnode = result.getString("Detail_Type");

            if (!headernode.equals(previousheadernode))

            {
                node1 = new TreeItem(headernode, headernode);
                root.add(node1);
                previousheadernode = headernode;


            }

            ArrayList<TreeItem> node1Children = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();
            TreeItem node1Child1 = new TreeItem(childnode, childnode);
            node1Children.add(node1Child1);
            node1.setChildren(node1Children);

        }


        setListInstance(root);
    }
```

This is how I am creating tree.But the child nodes are not getting added to     the parent as required(D1 and D2 must be added to parent node H1).

Please suggest me the changes.Is there any other simple way to achieve the same?

My table looks like this:

```
    header_details    detail_type   query
    --------------------------------------------------
    H1            D1            SELECT * FROM xyz;
    H1            D2            SELECT * FROM xyz;
    H2            D21           SELECT * FROM xyz;
    H2            D22           SELECT * FROM xyz;
    H3            D3            SELECT * FROM xyz;
    H3            D32           SELECT * FROM xyz;

    This is how I am creating tree.But the child nodes are not getting added to     the parent as required(D1 and D2 must be added to parent node H1).
```

Please suggest me the changes.Is there any other simple way to achieve the same?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You doing all wrong here, because its not the ADF way of doing things.
Learn how to use model and application module.

And there is a lot of sample how to work with tree model in adf:

- [Very nice firebox training video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON5AGc24DSc)
- [Tree table a bit more advanced component then just plain tree](http://andrejusb.blogspot.ru/2009/11/tree-table-component-in-oracle-adf.html)
- [Your own custom tree, if you for some reason don't like one based on model](http://yonaweb.be/creating_your_own_treemodel_adf_11g_0)
- [And don't forget about documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16181/af_table.htm)